# why Jquery .load() function is not firing on success?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, href

I have made a jquery functions which suppose to do 3 steps

1. onload it should replace attributes of all link files
2. when clicking it should load a sub page into $("#content")
3. again it should refire the function which would replace all links again

the following code works till 2 steps but doesnt fire third step which should replace all urls again I think it should replace also the links of loaded page?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var base_url = "http://localhost/dolphin/";
   $("a").each(function(e){
   if(this.href == "javascript:void(0)" || 
        this.href == base_url || 
        this.href == base_url + "index.php" || 
        this.href == "javascript:void(0);" || 
        this.href == "javascript:%20void(0)") {

     }else{
       page = 'Javascript:LoadPage(\''+ this.href + '\')';
       this.setAttribute('onclick',page);
       this.setAttribute('href', '#');
     }
   });
});

function LoadPage(url){
   $("#contentarea").load(url, function() {
     //after loading it should call redoIt() but it doesnt.
      redoIt();
   });
}

function redoIt(){
    var base_url = "http://localhost/dolphin/";
    $("a").each(function(e){
       if(this.href == "javascript:void(0)" || 
          this.href == base_url + "index.php" || 
          this.href == "javascript:void(0);" || 
          this.href == "javascript:%20void(0)") {

       }else{
         page = 'Javascript:LoadPage(\''+ this.href + '\')';
         this.setAttribute('onclick',page);
         this.setAttribute('href', '#');
       }
   });
 }
```

Comment: How do you know `redoIt()` isn't getting called?  Did you put a breakpoint in it?  Or a `console.log()` statement at the beginning?  Are there any javascript errors in the error console?  Are you sure that `LoadPage()` is getting called?

Comment: Your way to select links is truly horrible.... Haven't seen such a horrible misuse of jQuery for a long, long time.

Comment: i have added alert(this.href) in redoIt() but no reply came

Comment: @ThiefMaster can you please tell me how to do it better? instead of commenting?

Comment: Use a class name and select by that class. To bind a click event, use `$(this).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); /* your code here */ });` Avoid `javascript:` urls

Comment: @ThiefMaster I have tried $("body").on but it doesnt work therefore i am using simple and easy go function

Comment: You should bind the click event to your links, not to the body. Use `$('link_selector').click`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `$.load` is inside a function, and from what I gather you're not calling that anywhere so it's not getting executed. Take it out and it should work fine

```
$("#contentarea").load(url, function() {

//after loading it should call redoIt() but it doesnt.
 redoIt();
});
```